# laravel sanctum multiple subdomain auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I have 2 subdomain (client and client2)
client.domain.local
client2.domain.local

The problem is, when im login with credential in client.domain.local it was successful, but client2.domain.local automatic login, even though I logged in client.domain.local, when i press logout in client2.domain.local, both of website is logout, let me clear this:

1. client.domain.local login in otherside client2.domain.local will be login (even if i use credential username & password for client.domain.local)
2. client2.domain.local logout in otherside client.domain.local will be logout too

im using laravel sanctum, I've looked for it everywhere but can't get the answer for this case dynamic subdomain sanctum

.env

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=client.domain.local,client2.domain.local
SESSION_DOMAIN=.domain.local
```

sanctum.php

```
    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : '',
        env('FRONTEND_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('FRONTEND_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),
```

auth.php

```
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'client' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'clients',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],
        'clients' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\ClientUser::class,
        ],
    ],
```

1. How can client.domain.local login but client2.domain.local not login?
2. How can client.domain.local logout but client2.domain.local not logout?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [multi-domain package](https://github.com/gecche/laravel-multidomain). Each domain will have its own configuration `.env` and authentication.